# Troubleshooting K8 cluster with StatefulSets that don't respond to scales

Tags: kubernetes, troubleshooting, microk8s

I currently have a Kubernetes environment which is generally not behaving (slow response times to commands, pods not being scheduled, etc).

I've not been able to find any trouble shooting information in the form of events or errors (that I've encountered) that are pointing me to what is causing the issue.

What I'm asking is what are some general ways I can start getting the health status of the cluster, and start trying to find out what's going wrong here.

I've seen `kubectl cluster-info dump` suggested, but that gives me like 600K lines of metadata, where nothing obvious stands out (though it is 600k lines so I might have missed something).

Answer (score 0):

If a pod isn't being scheduled, there should be a reason in the Event section of the description for the pod :

```
kubectl describe pod <podname>
```

When this doesn't make any sense, next thing I do is look at nodes status and see if anything is not in a Ready state :

```
kubectl get node
```

Lastly, I go on a worker node and look at system logs for anything from kubelite

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: Thanks, I get nothing from the first two, but will look through these syslogs today to see if anything stands out.